# Get random terms

Tags: wp-query, terms

Is it possible to get random terms? To get random posts you could use `WP_Query` and set `'orderby' => 'rand'`.

But is there any way to do that with terms?

I've tried this:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'webshops',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'number' => 6
) );
```

Comment: random anything is very bad for caching. if you have no preference about which terms to display, the latest N is as random to the user of the site as any other set of terms ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike a normal `WP_Query()`, `get_terms()` or `WP_Term_Query()` does not have random ordering. You would either need to do it in SQL yourself or grab all the terms and [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) them, [pulling out 6](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to make your random term array:

```
// Get all terms
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'webshops',
    'hide_empty'    => false,
) );

// Randomize Term Array
shuffle( $terms );

// Grab Indices 0 - 5, 6 in total
$random_terms = array_slice( $terms, 0, 6 );
```