# Get random out from get_terms()

Tags: terms

I am trying to get Random terms from function "get_terms()", even though. I have found here this answered before and marked it as the best answer, But looks like that's not working anymore.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work anymore?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270121/get-random-terms/353896#353896


this is the post which has same question but the solutions isn't working anymore.

Comment: What happens instead? How did you debug the problem?

Comment: @GuruBhajanSingh There's nothing about that answer that shouldn't work anymore, and it's not even using a WordPress function so your issue has nothing to do with the WordPress version. Perhaps your expectations of what "random" is is incorrect.